# too many initializers MQL4

Tags: c++, mql4

When I compile the code, it tells me that too many initializers. This is the code string; I don't understand where the problem is:

```
string op_str[5] = { "BUY","SELL","BUYLIMIT","SELLLIMIT","BUYSTOP","SELLSTOP"};
```

Comment: You have an array of 5 strings, but you try to initialize it with 6 strings. What outcome do you expect?

Comment: Just remove `5`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

string op_str[6] = { "BUY","SELL","BUYLIMIT","SELLLIMIT","BUYSTOP","SELLSTOP"};

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.